# Why doesn't println of list behave like a list comprehension?

Tags: clojure, list-comprehension

Why doesn't my println (last line of example) act like a list comprehension? I'm trying the following code to get a solution to Project Euler's Problem #2 in Clojure:

```
(def fibsq [0 1])

(defn second-to-last [sq]
  (nth sq (- (count sq) 2)))

(second-to-last fibsq)

(defn add-last-two [sq]
  (+ (last sq) (second-to-last sq)))

(defn add-to-fibsq [sq]
  (if (< (add-last-two sq) 100)
    (add-to-fibsq (conj sq (add-last-two sq)))
    sq))

;; putting it all together
(add-to-fibsq fibsq)

(println [x (add-to-fibsq fibsq) :when (even? x)])
```

The output I get is the following:

> (def ||[0 1]|| [0 1])
>
> (defn second-to-last [||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]||]   (nth ||[0
>   1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]|| (- (count ||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
>   89]||) 2)))
>
> (second-to-last ||[0 1]||)|| => 0||
>
> (defn add-last-two [||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]||]   (+ (last
>   ||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]||) (second-to-last ||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8
>   13 21 34 55 89]||)))
>
> (defn add-to-fibsq [||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]||]   (if (<
>   (add-last-two ||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]||) 100)
>       (add-to-fibsq (conj ||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]|| (add-last-two ||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]||)))
>       ||[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89]||))
>
> ;; putting it all together (add-to-fibsq ||[0 1]||)|| => [0 1 1 2 3 5
>   8 13 21 34 55 89]||
>
> (println [x (add-to-fibsq ||[0 1]||) :when (even? x)])|| =>
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: x in this
>   context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:19:2)||

Is this not how list comprehensions work?

Comment: I don't have immediate access to Project Euler. Could you edit your question to include a brief statement of what you're trying to solve? tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure does not have standalone list-comprehensions like you are trying to use in that last line. you would need to put a call to `for` at the start of your last expression.

```
(println (for [x (add-to-fibsq fibsq) :when (even? x)] x))
```

It is the `for` function that binds the value to x for each entry in the results of calling `(add-to-fibsq fibsq)`. In this context even `for` is more than required

```
(println (filter even? (add-to-fibsq fibsq)))
```